# WPF TabItem Style screws up the control positions

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a new TabItem Style which looks the way I wanted. But now it screws up the positions of all the controls which are placed on the TabItem. It moves them from the top left area to the right bottom area of the TabItem. Any help would be highly appreciated. (Yes, I am sure I need the style in C# NOT in XAML)

```
var functionReturnValue = new Style();

ControlTemplate L_NewControlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(TabItem));
FrameworkElementFactory L_ElemFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
L_ElemFactory.SetBinding(Border.FocusVisualStyleProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding { RelativeSource = System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource.TemplatedParent, Path = new PropertyPath("FocusVisualStyle") });
L_ElemFactory.SetBinding(Border.BackgroundProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding { RelativeSource = System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource.TemplatedParent, Path = new PropertyPath("Background") });
L_ElemFactory.SetBinding(Border.BorderBrushProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding { RelativeSource = System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource.TemplatedParent, Path = new PropertyPath("BorderBrush") });
L_ElemFactory.SetBinding(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding { RelativeSource = System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource.TemplatedParent, Path = new PropertyPath("BorderThickness") });
//L_ElemFactory.SetValue(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(0,12,0,0));
L_ElemFactory.SetValue(Border.SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty, true);
FrameworkElementFactory L_ContentPresenter = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter));
L_ContentPresenter.SetValue(ContentPresenter.ContentSourceProperty, "Header");
L_ContentPresenter.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding { RelativeSource = System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource.TemplatedParent, Path = new PropertyPath("HorizontalContentAlignment") });
L_ContentPresenter.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.VerticalAlignmentProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding { RelativeSource = System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource.TemplatedParent, Path = new PropertyPath("VerticalContentAlignment") });
L_ContentPresenter.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.SnapsToDevicePixelsProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding { RelativeSource = System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource.TemplatedParent, Path = new PropertyPath("SnapsToDevicePixels") });
L_ElemFactory.AppendChild(L_ContentPresenter);
L_NewControlTemplate.VisualTree = L_ElemFactory;

Trigger NewTrigger;
//Trigger IsEnabled = true
NewTrigger = new Trigger { Property = TabItem.IsEnabledProperty, Value = true };
NewTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.ForegroundProperty, F_Foreround));
NewTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.BackgroundProperty, F_Background));
L_NewControlTemplate.Triggers.Add(NewTrigger);


//Trigger MouseOver
NewTrigger = new Trigger { Property = TabItem.IsMouseOverProperty, Value = true };
NewTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.ForegroundProperty, F_Foreround));
NewTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.BackgroundProperty, F_MouseOver));
L_NewControlTemplate.Triggers.Add(NewTrigger);

//Trigger Selected
NewTrigger = new Trigger { Property = TabItem.IsSelectedProperty, Value = true };
NewTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.ForegroundProperty, F_Foreround));
NewTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.BackgroundProperty, F_Background));
L_NewControlTemplate.Triggers.Add(NewTrigger);

//Trigger Selected
NewTrigger = new Trigger { Property = TabItem.IsSelectedProperty, Value = false };
NewTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.BackgroundProperty, L_IsDeActive));
L_NewControlTemplate.Triggers.Add(NewTrigger);

functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.FocusVisualStyleProperty, null));
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.BackgroundProperty, F_Background));
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Green));
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0)));
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.ForegroundProperty, F_Foreround));
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center));
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.VerticalContentAlignmentProperty, System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center));
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(0)));
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.MarginProperty, new Thickness(-4, -4, 0, 0)));
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.TemplateProperty, L_NewControlTemplate));
return functionReturnValue;
```

Comment: Why do you think you need this in C# not in XAML? It's not a coincidence that essentially nobody who knows WPF well does this stuff in C#. I certainly have little desire to try to translate the above code into terms that make any sense to me. It's your life, but you'd get quite a lot more help if you met us halfway on this.

Comment: I tried your code. It centers the content, which appears to be your intent since you're setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` both to `Center`.. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thx, that was the reason for the screwed up positions. My intent was actually only to center the ItemHeader. Now I just need to figure out how to center only the ItemHeader content. The reason for doing it in C# is that I need to change part of the styles dynamically within the runtime.

Comment: Try setting `TabItem.HeaderTemplate` in the TabItem Style. IIRC the ControlTemplate for the headers is defined in the TabControl template.

Comment: Not getting it:-( Do I need to create a separate template for the TabItem.HederTemplate

Comment: XAML provides many powerful ways for styles to alter themselves at runtime. ... What aren't you getting?

Comment: Creating a HeaderedContentControl...

Comment: Please explain in English exactly what you are now trying to do and what problems you encountered in trying to do it. Your last comment communicated very little.

Comment: I try to create a separate template for the TabItemHeader so I can set it using functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.HeaderTemplateProperty, L_ItemHeaderTemplate));

Comment: Right, that'll be a DataTemplate. Just stick a Label in there with margins or something. In XAML `<TabItem.HeaderTemplate><DataTemplate><Label Content="{Binding}" Margin="12" /></DataTemplate></TabItem.HeaderTemplate>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out your first problem is these two lines:

```
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center));
functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.VerticalContentAlignmentProperty, System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center));
```

Just omit those; they're acting on the tab item content, not on the header.

To restyle the header, you have a lot of options.

This will put a 20 unit margin around your content presenter:

```
L_ContentPresenter.SetValue(ContentPresenter.MarginProperty, new Thickness(20));
```

20's pretty arbitrary; of course you can use your own values. This will give it 20 unit side margins and 10 unit top/bottom margins:

```
L_ContentPresenter.SetValue(ContentPresenter.MarginProperty, new Thickness(20, 10, 20, 10));
```

You could also put a `Border` or something inside the header control template, surrounding the `ContentPresenter`, and do something with the padding or margins of that containing control. This kind of thing is infinitely easier to work with in XAML, so I'm not going to the trouble of doing that in C#.

You could have the `TabItem` style set `HeaderTemplate`, which is a `DataTemplate`:

```
var headerTemplate = new DataTemplate();
var label = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));

label.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding());

label.SetValue(Label.MarginProperty, new Thickness(16, 12, 16, 12));

headerTemplate.VisualTree = label;

functionReturnValue.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.HeaderTemplateProperty, headerTemplate));
```

**In closing, I'd like to reiterate that whatever you need to do at runtime to Styles, you can do more easily and far more maintainably in XAML than in C#.**